# Is it possible to create a route using a wildcard?

Tags: java, spring-boot, routes, h2, cloud-foundry

Is it possible to enable all routes that fall under a specific context root?

For example, lets imagine my context root is the following:

```
myapp.apps.pivotal.com/head
```

Can I bind a route that will automatically allow access to the following:

```
myapp.apps.pivotal.com/head/login.do
myapp.apps.pivotal.com/head/login.jsp
myapp.apps.pivotal.com/head/test.do
myapp.apps.pivotal.com/head/test.do?jsessionid=0cca44ba4133b113
myapp.apps.pivotal.com/head/login.do?jsessionid=0bba7a7a788b31
```

For context, I am trying to use a H2 database but I am having problems connecting to it in the browser. I can get to the `/h2-console` page, but when I try to POST to `login.do` or `test.do` it keeps throwing a Whitelabel Error Page

Comment: Are you trying to run a struts app on PCF?

Comment: No my application is Spring Boot but the login.do and login.jsp is part of the H2 Database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a route, `myapp.example.com/foo` and map that route to an app A.

Ex: `cf create-route my-space example.com --hostname myapp --path foo`

Requests to `myapp.example.com/foo`, `myapp.example.com/foo/bar` and anything under `/foo` will all be routed to app A.

You do need to be aware that context path routing on CF does *not* rewrite URLs. Thus using the example above a request for `myapp.example.com/foo/bar` is passed to app A as exactly that, `/foo/bar`. The `/foo` is not stripped off.

When you configure app A, you need to have it listening for requests `/foo/bar`. If it's just listening for `/bar` you'll get a 404.

If you want the `/foo` to be stripped off Spring Boot can do this for you. You just need to set `server.contextPath=/foo` in `application.properties`.

As far as your H2 issues, there's not enough info for me to comment. If the above doesn't help, add more info like what you're seeing when you try to access the H2 console. The whitelabel error page has useful info on it, so definitely share that.

Hope that helps!